# iOS: Testing if frameworks are linked at run time

Tags: ios, testing, frameworks

I'm working on an iOS framework that depends on a lot of other frameworks -  Some are Apple's core frameworks, others are not. I'd like to add a function `checkIntegration` that can be invoked by a developer to check if she/he has all the necessary frameworks linked, but I don't know if that's even something you can test.

I know I can test if a class exists, or if a class that implements a protocol exists, but that's only if they are a part of the developer's source code. I tried detecting (for example) a `CoreLocation` class and I couldn't. I also can't ask developers are weakly-link frameworks.

Is what I want to do possible? thanks.

Comment: How will you distribute it? Will it be a cocoapod? If so, you can add dependencies in your `podspec`.

Comment: I am not using Cocoapods at the moment, just plain old github.